# Strange black bar in booktabs table doesn't go away

Tags: rules, booktabs, bugs

First of all, the following problem cannot be replicated on other machines. Creating a MWE solves the problem, but I have to solve it within the context of my thesis, which includes a preamble that is far too complex to share here fully. This is the part of it that lists the packages I'm using (the rest of it is concerned with citation formatting):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% ===== BASIC SETTINGS ======

% {{{

\usepackage{microtype} % For improved full justification
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % For clickable references
\usepackage{bookmark} % For bookmarks
\usepackage{comment} % For the "comment" environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{verbatim} % Probably also for the "comment" environment
\usepackage{setspace} % For line spacing
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nice tables
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % For adding text below the table
\usepackage{Tabbing} % For tabbing functions
\usepackage{longtable} % For extra long tables
\usepackage{subfig} % For subfigures
\usepackage{amsmath} % For math figures
\usepackage{empheq} % For boxes around equations
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{svg} % Include svg images
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=35mm]{geometry} % For page margins

% }}}

% For colours


%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt} % Use this for adjusting the margins of coloured rows
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}


% For Outlines 

% {
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=(\arabic*)}
% }

% Global indentation

\usepackage{indentfirst}

% Footnotes

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} %
\usepackage[indentfirst = false]{quoting} % This one and the one above remove indentation from footnotes, but allow the text to be indented nevertheless

% Header

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % optional
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
%\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
%\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
%\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Author Name}

% ========= FONT =============

%\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times New Roman

\usepackage[]{libertine} % Linux Libertine (with Old Style numerals)

% ===== LINGUISTICS STUFF ======

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{gb4e} % For linguistic examples, glosses etc.
\noautomath
\counterwithin{xnumi}{section} % the chngcntr way (preferred)
\counterwithin{exx}{section} % reset example counter every chapter

\usepackage[edges, linguistics]{forest} % Tree structures
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\forestset{
  downroof/.style={
    for children={
      if n=1{
        edge path'={
          (.parent first) -- (!u.parent anchor) -- (!ul.parent last) -- cycle
        }
      }{no edge}
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to compile the `booktabs` table below, a black bar appears in the first column which is supposed to say "Variety". In my document I've got more than 30 tables that follow the same structure, and this is the only one where this problem occurs. I've tried removing \toprule, deleting the first row of the table, placing the table somewhere else in the document etc. – to no avail. The black bar either stays or moves to down to the next row. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to get rid of it, as I'm planning to hand in my thesis this week and really don't want to resort to manipulating the file in a separate pdf editor. Thank you!

```
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
Variety & Person  & Reference & Total (\%) \\ \midrule
SING  & 1       & overt     & 586 (12.11\%)    \\
     &         & null      & 32 (0.66\%)      \\
     & 2       & overt     & 413 (8.54\%)    \\
     &         & null      & 4 (0.08\%)         \\
     & 3       & overt     & 428 (8.85\%)     \\
     &         & null      & 28 (0.52\%)    \\ 
    &   \textit{it}     & overt &  25 (0.52\%)  \\
    &       & null      & 5  (0.10\%) \\
    & \textit{there} & overt     & 56 (1.16\%) \\
    &       & null      &     1 (0.02\%) \\ \midrule
Sum  &         &           & 1578 (32.62\%)     \\ \midrule
HK  & 1       & overt     & 603 (13.42\%)     \\
     &         & null      & 11 (0.24\%)      \\
     & 2       & overt     & 469 (10.44\%)    \\
     &         & null      & 13 (0.29\%)        \\
     & 3       & overt     & 426 (9.48\%)     \\
     &         & null      & 42 (0.93\%)  \\  
    &   \textit{it}     & overt &  28 (0.58\%) \\
    &       & null      & 9 (0.19\%)  \\
    & \textit{there} & overt     & 63 (1.30\%)  \\
    &       & null      &     0 (0.00\%)  \\ \midrule
Sum  &         &           & 1664 (34.39\%)    \\ \midrule
GB  & 1       & overt     & 745 (16.59\%)     \\
     &         & null      & 9 (0.20\%)      \\
     & 2       & overt     & 304 (6.77\%)    \\
     &         & null      & 0  (0.00\%)        \\
     & 3       & overt     & 361 (8.03\%)     \\
     &         & null      & 18 (0.40\%)  \\ 
    &   \textit{it}     & overt &  61 (1.26\%)  \\
    &       & null      & 2 (0.04\%)  \\
    & \textit{there} & overt     & 96 (1.98\%)  \\
    &       & null      &     0 (0.00\%)  \\ \midrule
Sum  &         &           & 1586 (32.99\%)    \\ \midrule
Total   &          &          &   4838 (100\%) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption}\label{table:iv-1}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem, not  disconnected code fragments. Remove packages not related,eg do you need `\usepackage{wasysym}` to see this issue?

Comment: **(I)** Please merge your code fragments into one small document called MWE (Minimal Working Example)  with your table. **(ii)** which document class do you use? **(iii)** in preamble it should has only to your problem related packages and definitions, **(iii)** don't load some packages twice. If I add to your first code fragment missed `\documentclass` I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Comment out piece for piece until the problem goes away. Keep on removing stuff. Then make a minimal example showing only the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the TO outlined in a comment: it'S kind of variable. When reduced to a MWE, the result is fine. When used inside the (huge) thesis, something is wrong. Sounds like it's impossible to further localize the problem: as the TO stated "it's too long to be posted here".

Answer (score 2):

- Please consider my comment.
- With your code fragments merged in document and for documentclass use `article`, I can't reproduce your problem (tested by recent version of MiKTeX).
- Below is an example of MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem (mine works fine!) as we expect that you provide instead of shoved uncomplete code fragments.
- Requirements for MWE may Creating an MWE might   take some work/trial and error, but it will also help to isolate and identify the problem. There is more info in [What is MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

However, I would write your table on different way, which produce (to my opinion) more aesthetic and readable table:

[image]

MWE (Minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            vmargin={20mm, 20mm}, 
            hmargin={25mm, 35mm}
            ]{geometry}     % For page margins

\usepackage[]{libertine} % Linux Libertine (with Old Style numerals)

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}    % <--- new

\usepackage{lipsum}     % new, added for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66] % dummy text
    \begin{table}[htbp!]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} lll S[table-format=4.0] 
                        S[table-format=2.2]  @{}}
    \toprule
Variet  & Person    &    Reference & {Total}& {(\%)}   \\ 
    \midrule
SING    & 1             & overt     & 586   & 12.11 \\
        &               & null      & 32    & 0.66  \\
        & 2             & overt     & 413   & 8.54  \\
        &               & null      & 4     & 0.08  \\
        & 3             & overt     & 428   & 8.85  \\
        &               & null      & 28    & 0.52  \\
        & \textit{it}   & overt     & 25    & 0.52  \\
        &               & null      & 5     & 0.10  \\
        & \textit{there}& overt     & 56    & 1.16  \\
        &               & null      & 1     & 0.02  \\ 
    \midrule
Sum     &               &           & 1578  & 32.62 \\ 
    \midrule
HK      & 1             & overt     & 603   & 13.42 \\
        &               & null      & 11    & 0.24  \\
        & 2             & overt     & 469   & 10.44 \\
        &               & null      & 13    & 0.29  \\
        & 3             & overt     & 426   & 9.48  \\
        &               & null      & 42    & 0.93  \\
        & \textit{it}   & overt     & 28    & 0.58  \\
        &               & null      & 9     & 0.19  \\
        & \textit{there}& overt     & 63    & 1.30  \\
        &               & null      & 0     & 0.00  \\ 
    \midrule
Sum     &               &           & 1664  & 34.39 \\ 
    \midrule
GB      & 1             & overt     & 745   & 16.59 \\
        &               & null      & 9     & 0.20  \\
        & 2             & overt     & 304   & 6.77  \\
        &               & null      & 0     & 0.00  \\
        & 3             & overt     & 361   & 8.03  \\
        &               & null      & 18    & 0.40  \\
        & \textit{it}   & overt     & 61    & 1.26  \\
        &               & null      & 2     & 0.04  \\
        & \textit{there}& overt     & 96    & 1.98  \\
        &               & null      & 0     & 0.00  \\
    \midrule
Sum     &               &           & 1586  & 32.99 \\ 
    \midrule
Total   &               &           & 4838  & 100.00\\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A caption}\label{table:iv-1}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[1-5] % dummy text
\end{document}
```

This MWE can serve to define your document style. Add only needed packages (do you really need all of them?), take car that each package is loaded only ones.